# jQuery how to add class to the next iframe?

Tags: jquery

I have three `iframe` elements with the first being visible and all the others have a `display:none` style. The one that is visible has the class "visible". When the "next" button is clicked, I want the next iframe to show and the previous iframe to be hidden.

So i tried using `addClass` and `removeClass` but `addClass` doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#next").click(function(){

    $(".visible").next().show();
    $(".visible").next().addClass("visible");
    $(".visible").hide();
    $(".visible").removeClass("visible");

  });

});
```

The elements are:

```
<iframe class="iframe visible" src="a.html" width="100%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe class="iframe" src="b.html" width="100%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe class="iframe" src="c.html" width="100%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Why does `removeClass()` work and `addClass()` doesn't?

Comment: Is this your actual HTML or are there elements/tags in between? You have to be sure about the `DOM traversal` here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this instead

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#next").click(function () {
        $('.visible').removeClass('visible').hide().next().show().addClass('visible');
    });
});
```

Right now you're adding the class `.visible` to the next element, and on the next line you're hiding all elements with that class, see commented version of your code below

```
$(".visible").next().show();              // show the next one
$(".visible").next().addClass("visible"); // add .visible class to the next one
$(".visible").hide();         // -- > now you're hiding both the next and current
$(".visible").removeClass("visible");     // and then you're removing the class
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/U86wP/)

Comment: Ok, have to go back to jQuery collection selector 101 here. ;)

Comment: @dollarvar It's quite easy actually. First find an element, do some stuff with it (hide, add class) then refine your selection with the `next()` selector and do some stuff with *that* element.

Comment: @BramVanroy Well, I wondered how the `.next()` of a collection `$('.visible')` could aim at the next `iframe`. But it seems that jQuery selects the next `sibling` on the base of same HTML element here.

Comment: @dollar Indeed. Even though it might be confusing with the use of classes here that can have multiple occurences, the use here is limited to a single element and, thus, only one possible *next* element.

Comment: @BramVanroy Yeah, but I thought "hey, there is no next `.visible`." ;)

Comment: @BramVanroy If I could show you the deleted answer of mine, where Adoneo was so nice to point my misconception out without downvoting (Thanks!), you would understand what I mean. But this is why I am commenting here.

Comment: @adeneo can I specify that I want this to work only on iframes?

Comment: @dollarvar - `next()` selects the next element, doesn't matter what it is, what class it has etc. it **only** targets the next element in the DOM. You can pass a selector to `next('.someclass')`, and then it filters the next element, so that it only returns the element if it matches that class, but it still only ever works on the next element, you ***can not*** traverse the DOM any further with `next()`, *ever*, then you'd have to use `nextUntil`, `nextAll` etc.

Comment: Yeah, but only the next **sibling**, like in "next iframe", would not work for "next element of iframe" if this is a `div`, right?!? http://api.jquery.com/next/ @Tom Haha, I adressed that in my answer, but I am in fear of getting downvoted when I show you (undelete) that.

Comment: Seems like I have to grasp the concept of "sibling" here, hmmm. :(

Comment: @dollarvar - That's right, `next()` only gets the next element, if the next element is not the iframe but something else, it needs to be handled differently, and that's why it's important to try and get everything right in the question, as there's different ways to do this depending on wether or not the next iframe is the next element, a sibling somewhere, or just the next iframe in the DOM order, anywhere ?

Comment: Haha, then my comment on OP was right. ;) However I just cracked it: Sibling is EVERYTHING inside a tag. I thought sibling would be "of same tag". ;)

Comment: @dollarvar - Yup, siblings are all the element that are, well siblings inside the same parent element. It also accepts a selector as a filter only.

Answer (score 0):

It works! but you make 1st and 2nd iframes visible, then hide both of them and remove class from both of them